# Next.js: How to remove # from the slug when referring to an element by id

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

How to remove **#** from the URL when referring to an element by id (change *domain.com/**#contact*** to *domain.com/**contact***)?

e.g.: After clicking this link: `<Link href="about"><a>Contact</a></Link>` the page will scroll to the element with `#contact` id and the URL will be *domain.com/**#contact***.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to remove the hash part `/#contact` entirely, OR replace it with `/contact` (without the #)?

Comment: @juliomalves I want to replace it. It is a single-page web and I need to use the id of the section to navigate on this web.  So when the user click e.g. Contact in the nav, it will scroll down to contact section and the slug will be ***domian.com/contact***, no ***domain.com/#contact***.

The best will be if the slug will change automatically when the user scrolls down (e.g. the user is on the top of the website - no slug: ***domain.com***; when he scrolls down to contact section - slug will be contact: ***domain.com/contact***), but this is not so necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Add the id attribute to the contact div like so`<div id="contact">Contact</div>`, then your link should be this `<Link href="/about#contact"><a>Contact</a></Link>`